# Cannot find symbol for hasNext() and next() methods for my Java card game

Tags: java, exception, methods, io

It has a red underline under the hasNext() and next() methods.  The error it gives is:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol: method hasNext()
>
> location: variable deck of type Deck

It shows the same error for the next() method.  I tried creating a new Deck object by adding `deck = new Deck();` within the House constructor but it gives me the error:

> unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

I've googled what that means and read that maybe I need a try catch block but I don't exactly understand why.

```
public class House
{
    private double currentBet;          // Player's current bet
    private double pot;                 // Amount of the pot in play
    private Card firstCard;             // First card to be dealt
    private Card secondCard;            // Second card to be dealt
    private Card thirdCard;             // Third card to be dealt
    private Deck deck;                  // The card deck to be used
    private DeckIterator deckIterator;  // The card deck to be used

   /**
     * Private helper method that returns the next card in the deck.  
     * If the end of the deck is reached, it shuffles the deck and 
     * returns the first card off the deck.
     * @return Card card;
     */ 
    private Card dealCard()
    {
        if(!deck.hasNext())
        {
            deck.shuffle();
        }
        return deck.next();
    }
```

This is a snippet of the Deck class.  This was written by another team member:

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck;
    private int currentCard; //index of next card to be dealt
    private int remainingCards;
    private BufferedImage tempCardImage;


    /**
     * Constructor to build a deck of cards
     */
    public Deck () throws IOException
    {
    String[] Faces = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen",
                        "King", "Ace"};
    String[] Suits = {"Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    deck = new Card[52];
    currentCard = 0;

    ~~~irrelevant code here~~~ 
    }

public Iterator<Card> iterator(){
    return new DeckIterator( this );
}

public class DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card> {
    private Deck d;
    private int pos;
    DeckIterator( Deck d ){
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return pos < d.deck.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Card next(){
        if( pos >= d.deck.length ){
            throw new NoSuchElementException( "No more cards in deck" );
        }
        return d.getCard( pos++ );
    }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); }
}
}
```

**This is my modified code using the suggestions made by you guys:**

```
public class House
{
    private double currentBet;          // Player's current bet
    private double pot;                 // Amount of the pot in play
    private Card firstCard;             // First card to be dealt
    private Card secondCard;            // Second card to be dealt
    private Card thirdCard;             // Third card to be dealt
    private Deck deck;                  // The card deck to be used

    DeckIterator deckIterator = deck.iterator();

    /**
     * Constructor that receives that amount of the buy in and sets the pot.
     * @param buyIn 
     */
    public House(double buyIn)
    {     
        pot = buyIn;
    }

   /**
     * Private helper method that returns the next card in the deck.  
     * If the end of the deck is reached, it shuffles the deck and 
     * returns the first card off the deck.
     * @return Card card;
     */ 
    private Card dealCard()
    {
        if(!deckIterator.hasNext())
        {
            deck.shuffle();
        }
        try
        {
            deckIterator.next();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return deckIterator.next();
    }
```

Comment: you need to show the signature for Deck class

Comment: Those methods are in `DeckIterator`, not `Deck`.  You'll need a variable of type `DeckIterator` if you're going to call them.

Comment: What is inside your Deck class? If it is not a collection then you cannot use those two methds

Comment: Sorry I added more of the Deck class now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that exception because in `next()` you `throw new NoSuchElementException`. When you use `next()`, such as in `dealCard()`, you need to handle cases where this exception is indeed thrown.

Therefore, you need to put `deck.next()` in a try-catch block.

```
try {
    return deck.next()
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DeckIterator` essentially wraps the `Deck` type. `Deck` has an `iterator()` method, so you'll just need to do this:

```java
DeckIterator deckIterator = deck.iterator();
```

Then in `dealCard` replace the `deck` references with `deckIterator`.

And as others pointed out, you need to use a `try/catch` around the call to `deckIterator.next()`.

Comment: Thank you! I have added my modified code.  For DeckIterator, it gives me the error **"cannot find symbol: class DeckIterator. location: class House"**.  In the `System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());` it gives me the error **"void type not allowed here"**.  Sorry, I'm probably doing something very simple wrong.

Comment: Make sure your `House.java` file imports the appropriate package where `DeckIterator` is defined. Also, you're declaring `DeckIterator deckIterator = ...` in the `House` constructor. You need to move the declaration to the class instead of constructor, with the rest of your variable declarations.

Comment: Thank you again.  I have modified my code again, it is not giving me any errors.  Could you please check if it looks alright this time?  Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer because I just realized `Deck` has an `iterator()` method.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated my code, it underlines `DeckIterator deckIterator = deck.iterator();` and gives the message: **"incompatible types: Iterator<Card> cannot be converted to Deck.DeckIterator"**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trying to use hasNext() and next() from the `DeckIterator` class.

Replace `private Deck deck;` with `private DeckIterator deckIterator;`

Comment: Gave me something to take into consideration next time, thank you!